# Remembering user preferences and delivering information based on them

Tags: ios5, rss

I was wondering what technologies are needed to develop and app that uses different RSS feeds to make a newspaper (i.e. AOL's Editions) and then remember the user's preferences and deliver content based on what the user tends to read most.

I am particularly interested in the process behind the "remembering" and "delivering customized content".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the remembering part, look up NSUserDefaults in the class reference documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wenderlich has a great [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial) on working with RSS feeds that you should check out. If nothing else, it'll give you something to work with, which is always infinitely better than having to start from scratch.

Also, see the Apple documentation on [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which is used to store user preferences.